# Gaussian Process vs Linear regression: Prediction error

Tags: gaussian-process, prediction-interval

I'm trying to learn GP and every manual says that GP can deliver predictions **with uncertainty**. Now, as I have learned some linear regression, I don't understand why is that a big deal. The simplest glm model (or even a spline model which is "closer" to GP) will provide this uncertainty as well.

Why in GP this seems like an amazing feature?

Comment: Normally regression models provide point estimates. GP has a closed form co-variance computation, so it can provide prediction interval by construction. See Ghahramani's notes [here](https://bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/farm/mlss/uploads/Site/lect1gp.pdf).

Comment: @msuzen, indeed lm returns point estimators but it can still provide uncertainty estimation. On the other hand, Bayesian lm gives the probabilistic answers. But again it's not clear to me why GP's uncertainty estimation is so special deal. 
Of course, it's not clear to me why everyone refers to GP intervals as Confidence and not  Credible.